# What items can be enchanted?

Tags: candy-box-2

I'm wondering if I need to continue saving chocolate for enchanting items or if I can make them all into pain au chocolait.  In order to know when I can stop worrying about chocolate bars, I need to know what can be enchanted.

So what items can be enchanted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is a complete list, anyone feel free to correct me.

1. Leather Gloves - 2 Enchantments
2. Monkey Wizard Staff - 1 Enchantment
3. Octopus King Crown - 2 Enchantments
4. Knight Body Armour - 1 Enchantment
5. Tribal Spear - 1 Enchantment
6. Giant Spoon - 1 Enchantment

2 + 1 + 2 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 8

So you need 8 Chocolate Bars to Enchant everything.

Answer (score 2):

Given you get better equipment along the way and only the "gifts" can be used simultaneously as opposed to e.g. red and pink gloves or Jasper crown and sorceress hat, I saved almost all the chocolate for pain au chocolats in my latest play-through.
I enchanted the gloves (pink - way better than red) and kept a spare chocolate bar in case I decided to go with the Giant Spoon of Doom, leaving me with 11 pain au chocolats for 6x magic, 4x power and 1x health.

I chose to not enchant the armour because since the non-enchanted knight body armour
already gives you 30% damage resistance, the enchantment in itself only gives you +50% resistance for the -50% damage output, effectively halving both your and your opponent's DPS, and since you need your DPS to be higher than your opponent's in the first place, this is actually a bad deal for you unless you also get the xeno claws.

A great tip for getting early into the castle for pain au chocolats:
As soon as you

> have the sponge,

you can

> squeeze to run between the horses' legs, getting past the knights quickly with almost no damage taken! To get the armor, you only have to kill one of the knights.

Comment: "effectively halving both your and your opponent's DPS" No. You go from 70% damage taken (100-30) to 20% taken (100-80) so you reduce your opponent's DPS by a factor 3.5. Therefore the "you over enemy" DPS ratio is improved by a factor 1.75 when you enchant the armor, which is far from being negligible (and muuuch better than a 1.2 pain-au-chocolat). On top of that, it goes nicely with the pink gloves, since they will have 3.5 times less to heal.